# In Angular, the openWeatherMap some errors in the console

Tags: openweathermap

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=11.01&lon=76.95&appid=fc71701585d65027375c8517dadebf21:1  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
above this error is came in the console and how to get the values in the component in angular

Comment: There is a problem with your api key. Remove the :1 and the request will work.

    https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=11.01&lon=76.95&appid=fc71701585d65027375c8517dadebf21

Comment: but my api key is correct. so why this problem is coming?